# why does using _ in between spaces not work (python, trying to get the mean of a column)

Tags: python, pandas

(i'm new to python/machine learning as a whole, sorry if i'm not using the write terminology)
so whenever you write the name of a column you're referring to, you use _ between words, right? but in my case the code won't work when i use _ and instead worked with spaces.
when it doesn't work:
`df['Number_of_U.S._Representatives'].mean()`
vs when it does:
`df['Number of U.S. Representatives'].mean()`
when i run the first example i get an error of KeyError: 'Number_of_U.S._Representatives'
why is that?

Comment: Putting underscore between words is just a convention, what matters is that the string you put in the brackets is the actual name of a column in your dataframe.

Comment: Because `' ' != '_'`... it's good practice to use `_` where spaces should be, but it's not going to put them there for you.

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is just one more character, there's nothing special about it and replacing `'Number of U.S. Representatives'` by `'Number_of_U.S._Representatives'` has the same effect as doing `'NumberAofBU.S.CRepresentatives'`: it's just not going to work because there's no column called like that and you'll get a KeyError.

pandas offers a convenient way of referencing columns as attributes, using the dot notation. So, if a DataFrame `df`has a column called `Date`, you can reference it either as `df['Date']` or `df.Date`. The former one is the *default* and the later just for convenience. Because a lot of people like yo use the second one, it's usual to replace whitespaces in names of columns by underscores. For example, in your case it would be impossible to use the dot notation since `df.Number of U.S. Representatives` would be interpreted by the interpreter as a reference to `df.Number` (a column called 'Number', which doesn't exist) followed by some instruction `of U.S. Representatives` which is meaningless. That's probably why you have seen this before.